# How to gain access to an element in a dynamically created table?

Tags: javascript, search

I have a table which I dynamically fill with a data set filtered from drop down menus.The data is filtered by index (selectedIndex).

```
var table = document.getElementById("weather");
for (var i=0; i<indexSelected.length; i++) {
    var row=table.insertRow(i+1);
    var time=row.insertCell(0);
    var siteName=row.insertCell(1);
    var region=row.insertCell(2);
    var sigWeather=row.insertCell(3);
    var screenTemp=row.insertCell(4);
    time.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["time"];
    siteName.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["siteName"];
    region.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["region"];
    sigWeather.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["sigWeather"];
    screenTemp.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["screenTemp"];
}
```

I am trying to them search for a particular element in this table. For example, the table lists screen temperatures, I have already worked out the minimum screen temperature and would like to search for it in the table. One this is done, I need to change the background colour to this cell, however, I have no idea how to go about this. I would appreciate some help. I can only use Javascript for this.

Comment: Which one is "`a particular element`"? How do you recognize it? By content, by `id`, by location in the table? And what is the situation you want to change the style?

Comment: It is recognised by content, sorry, have now mentioned that. None of the elements have an id associated with them, only the table does.

Comment: Looks like the wanted cell is also recognized by location, it can be always found at column 5. You can iterate through cells using `#weather.rows[r].cells[4]`, push `textContent`s and cells to a 2D array, sort the array (if numbers, use a custom sort function) and finally pick your cell from `array[0][1]` and change the style.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed to know. Have managed to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Please check the jquery [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method

This two methods helps you to add event and give functionality to dynamically created object

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this line to the code that dynamically fills out your table:

```
var table = document.getElementById("weather");
for (var i=0; i<indexSelected.length; i++) {
    [... snip ...]

    screenTemp.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["screenTemp"];
    screenTemp.classList.add('screenTemp');
}
```

Then you can find it by doing `document.querySelector('.screenTemp')`

You could also just do your background color change right after you fill out the info:

```
var table = document.getElementById("weather");
for (var i=0; i<indexSelected.length; i++) {
    [... snip ...]

    screenTemp.innerHTML=weather[indexSelected.length[i]]["screenTemp"];
    changeBgColor(screenTemp);
}

function changeBgColor(screenTempCell) {
    // do your magic here
}
```